Implementation of Wiener-Hopf Beamformer in Matlab
I'm trying to implement a Wiener-Hopf beamformer using the equation given in my lecture note:

Weiner-Hopf BF:

Maximizes SNR in MMSE sense: $\mathbf{w} \!\left( \theta \right) = \mathbf{R}_{\textrm{xx}}^{-1} \mathbf{a} \!\left( \theta \right)$


Where:

$\mathbf{R}_{\textrm{xx}}=\mathbf{E}\{xx^H\}$


$\mathbf{a} \!\left( \theta \right)= \begin{bmatrix}1 & e^{j2\pi\Delta\sin(\theta)} & e^{j4\pi\Delta\sin(\theta)} & \cdots & e^{j2(N-1)\pi\Delta\sin(\theta)}\end{bmatrix}^T$ is the steering vector


M: number of emitting sources.


N: number of sensors


doa_angles_deg: Desired direction of arrivals in deg.

This piece of code I wrote is for implementing this BF to a $12 \times 500$ signal $x$, which I already know the value of the DoAs $= \left[ -18, 3, 18, 35 \right]$
    N = 12;         % Number of sensors
    L = 500;        % number of samples
    Delta = 0.5;
    Rxx = (x*x')/L; % Devide by L
    ...
    doa_angles_deg = [-18, 3, 18, 35];
    % c1. Design a Wiener-Hopf beamformer
  

    Theta = deg2rad(doa_angles_deg);

    A = zeros(N,M);
    for m = 1:M
        a = exp(1j*2*pi*(0:N-1)*Delta*sin(Theta(m)));
        A (:,m) = a;
    end
    % Wiener's beamforming vector
    w_w = inv(Rxx)*A; 
    
    % Define range of angles for beam pattern
    theta_range = linspace(-pi/2, pi/2, 360); % Angles from -90 to 90 degrees
    B = zeros(N,length(theta_range));
    for m = 1:length(theta_range)
        b = exp(1j*2*pi*(0:N-1)*Delta*sin(theta_range(m)));
        B (:,m) = b;
    end
    BP = w_w'*B;

In the results, however, the desired angles were not focused, as you can see in the figure below:

So where could I be doing wrong? I suspect there's a problem with how I calculated the weight vector, but I could not find it.

Can you share the omplete code? It seems you skipped some part of the code and it is not clear where x is defined and what is M.

@learner has a point. Especially the signal data are quite important here. I suspect there is something wrong with your $\mathbf{R}{\textrm{xx}}$ matrix. I may be wrong (as there’s quite some information missing here) but I believe $\mathbf{R}{\textrm{xx}}$ is the result of an expectation operator, which is not very clear on how exactly you calculate it here (or I am just missing something).

Oh M here is the number of emitting sources, which I had to determine before doing this. The process was: A signal x was given -> Find the number of emitting sources and their DoAs then implement beamforming. Rxx is the autocorrelation matrix. @learner

@learner https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BfH4NWqRuu_yY-i9sIkPa4ixUZpH98x3/view?usp=drive_link
Here's the signal

Are you sure you have the geometry correct? I get something that looks more reasonable with cosine, but still seems incorrect.

@Baddioes Yes It came straight out from the note:
a(theta) = [1, exp(j2pi*delta*sin(theta),exp(j4pi*delta*sin(theta),...,exp(j(N-1)pi*delta*sin(theta)]^T

If you take the mean of your BP, you get nulls at the desired angles. If you invert your BP, you will see nice peaks. If you want beams at the desired angles you need to do: 10log10(mean(abs(RxxB))).

I think your Weiner-Hopf equation needs correction, can you share link to your notes? if d is the desired signal and X the input delayline matrix then usually least-squares solution is something like: w = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}d. What is the desired output in your case?

Your weights $w$ should be calculated over a range of angles and applied to your signal vector $x$, not by some steering vector, $\mathbf{B}$.
So, for each angle between $-90^{\textrm{o}}$ and $90^{\textrm{o}}$ (or whatever your desired coverage area is), calculate $w$ then apply it to your input signal vector $x$ (or a new signal vector, provided the target of interest is still observable). This gives you one value. Plot these values vs your angles.
